# Ionic Cordova in IOS Library not loaded: OneSignal.framwork i already added OneSignal.framwork in Frameworks Libraries and Embedded Content

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have using ionic cordova my app build successfully but when app run on device it crash with error dyld[56415]: Library not loaded: @rpath/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal. i have already tried adding OneSignal.xcframework on General Tab -> Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content.
but i am still having same error.
[image]

> dyld[56415]: Library not loaded: @rpath/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal
> Referenced from: <412C7AB6-2BAD-3663-9D1D-FB3261E0953D>
> /Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FDE04AD4-CA22-4B4F-8884-EFE6D90024AF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C9136F4A-D63E-462F-8364-A98356CAF083/YAAN.app/YAAN
> Reason: tried:
> '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YAAN-guuzccmxmkychdcpumvuieulcvzh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal'
> (no such file),
> '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal'
> (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal' (no
> such file, not in dyld cache),
> '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FDE04AD4-CA22-4B4F-8884-EFE6D90024AF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C9136F4A-D63E-462F-8364-A98356CAF083/YAAN.app/Frameworks/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal'
> (no such file),
> '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal'
> (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal' (no
> such file, not in dyld cache),
> '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FDE04AD4-CA22-4B4F-8884-EFE6D90024AF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C9136F4A-D63E-462F-8364-A98356CAF083/YAAN.app/Frameworks/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal'
> (no such file),
> '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal'
> (no such file) (lldb)